# Apache http.conf with wildcard subdomains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, lamp

I have a white-label web app that runs with subdomains to divide out the labels. Let's say `cust1.app.com` and `cust2.app.com`. I have SSL on my site, but I am having troubles making the site redirect from `http` to `https`. I want to do this all within `http.conf`, as opposed to `.htaccess` files. Here is my `http.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ServerAlias *.app.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/app

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/certs/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/certs/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/certs/fullchain.pem

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAlias *.app.com

    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

When visiting `http://www.app.com` or `http://cust1.app.com`, I get a simple `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, however when I manually put in the `https`, the site serves fine on all subdomains.

How do I redirect to https while honoring my wildcard subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the `Listen` directive for port 80, I must have deleted it from `ports.conf` or something at some point in the long and hair-pulling troubleshooting process. Here's my `http.conf` now:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ServerAlias *.app.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/app

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/certs/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/certs/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/certs/fullchain.pem

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAlias *.app.com

    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```